# How to Mock Static calls of external Jar

Tags: java, junit, static, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock the static calls of external jar. But the real method is getting calling . Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Method :

```
  public void method(){

  try{

  OutputClass output = StaticClass.getName("String","String");

  }catch(Eception e){

  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

Note : StaticClassOutput and OutputClass are frrom external jar.

I tried by using MockStatic also(Used Mockito inline 5.1.1 dependency). but it didnt work out..Original getName method is getting called. I want to mock the getName and return mock "OutputClass".

Tried solution :

```
 try(MockStatic<StaticClass> mockStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.Class)){

OutputClass output = Mockito.mock(OutputClass.Class);
mockStatic.when(()->StaticClass.getName(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(output);

}
```

This code is not working-getName real method is calling . Please help.

Comment: Where do you call `method`?

Comment: "method" is there in my current application class and its getting called from Service layer.

Comment: But where do you call it in the test?